# What is the gnome-shell equivalence in LXDE?

Tags: gnome-shell, lxde

https://www.mankier.com/1/gnome-shell says

> gnome-shell — Graphical shell for the GNOME desktop

In LXDE, what is the `gnome-shell` equivalence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see two moments:

1. GNOME Shell is a desktop environment based on Mutter for window management (while GNOME 2 used Metacity and one GNOME Panel or two).
2. In Lubuntu LXDE uses Openbox as window manager and [LXPanel](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel) (equivalent of old GNOME Panel). This is confirmed while running Lubuntu session.

**From this point of view - LXDE equivalence of GNOME Shell is Openbox.**

---

Some useful links:

1. [Wikipedia - GNOME Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell)
2. [Wikipedia - LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE)
3. [Wikipedia - Comparison of X Window System desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_Window_System_desktop_environments)